# JavaFX - Method for set LocalDateTime not working

Tags: java, javafx

I have a class called Sell which has a SimpleObjectProperty.
In the POJO, the getters and setters are the following:

```
private ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> sellDate;

....

public LocalDateTime getSellDate() {
    return sellDate.get();
}

public void setSellDate(LocalDateTime value) {
    sellDate.set(value);
}
```

When creating a new instance of the Sell class, I use the method `setSellDate()`:

```
....
Sell sell = new Sell();
//another gets and sets...
sell.setSellDate(LocalDateTime.now());
```

This line of code is giving me a NullPointerException.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize sellDate?

Comment: Is the first line: `private ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> sellDate;`

Comment: Do you actually initialize it anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sell` clearly isn't null, `sellDate` must be the reference that is null. You show where you declare it with

```
private ObjectProperty<LocalDateTime> sellDate;
```

but you don't show any code that initializes it. You need something like

```
sellDate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
```

in the constructor.